# Floating li items with css for more than one Ul items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's take this html code:

```
<div>

    <ul>
        <li>aaa</li>
         <li>bbb</li>
         <li>ccc</li>
    </ul>

      <ul>
        <li>ddd</li>
         <li>fff</li>
         <li>eee</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

The result is ok, of course. But, now I want to make all `li` items inside the `ul`s horizontally with the help of this `CSS`:

```
li{ 
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
```

But, the result is: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pv6rby9/1/)

I can add `</br>` between `div`'s. But, it is not the correct way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inline the `<ul>` elements inside the div.

```
ul {
    display:inline; 
    text-align:center; 
    margin:10px 0; // This is to avoid scrollbars in the demo, might not be necessary for you
    padding:0;
}

li {
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4pv6rby9/14/.

Comment: Sorry, but I have edited my answer. I don't want to centerize items. I just want to add next to the bottom of first ul.

Comment: Based on your first comment I updated my question. But I am confused now, my first post is actually correct?

Comment: Bro, you can actually remove ul style. ;) Life is brilliant bro as css :D yahoooo yahooooooo! :D

Answer (score 1):

Add a width property to li to distribute them horizontally and align the uls horizontally:

```
ul{
    text-align: center;
}
li{    
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 16.5%;
}
```

This will work for a fixed number of list items.

Answer (score 0):

use margin.

```
li{

    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Use clear both- 
HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <li>aaa</li>
         <li>bbb</li>
         <li>ccc</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <ul>
        <li>ddd</li>
         <li>fff</li>
         <li>eee</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of float, it will be much easier to position other elements on page.

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul{
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pv6rby9/13/)